# WebView for IOS and compatibility for IE browser pages

Tags: ios, xcode, webview

I made a project to run a page as web view in my Xcode project .

I was able to create this , but there is a problem in making it work as this page only works with **IE browsers** and not really opens on any other browsers.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let url = NSURL(string: "MYLINK")
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)

    webView.delegate = self

    activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true
    activityIndicator.startAnimating()
    webView.loadRequest(request)
}
```

Comment: If it's known to only work with IE, I think the answer is to fix the page.

Comment: And if that page is not yours to play , just give up on it ?

Comment: Maybe...or maybe talk to the owner about why it's that way.

Comment: And consider owner is a big governmental company with no wiseness on this matter and they won't listen and you have to use their service.